# Bypass disabled DL function PHP Linux

Tags: php, linux, function

I have a PHP shell on a Linux red-hat server with user privileges. I'm trying to symlink the root directory and still its impossible using `ln -s` or even `symlink()` in PHP.

I have seen that PHP DL function is disabled like this picture:

[image]

I used a **php.ini** in my current directory witch contain this string:

```
safe_mode=OFF
disable_functions=NONE
```

and it didn't disabled, so what to do?

Answer (score 1):

The `dl` function, and the ability to dynamically load PHP extensions, has been removed from all PHP SAPIs, *with exception of CLI SAPI*, since PHP 5.3 (and 7.0 in php-fpm).

> **Warning** This function was removed from most SAPIs in PHP 5.3.0, and was removed from PHP-FPM in PHP 7.0.0.
>
> [Source php.net/dl](http://php.net/dl)

So unless you're running PHP 5.2, there is no use for that function in a Web SAPI. You shouldn't be trying to dynamically load your extensions at runtime in a web environment anyway. It usually doesn't make any sense and can result in a lot of edge cases. Most of these edge cases are moot in a CLI environment, but matter to a web environment.

As for overriding `disable_functions` you want to make sure you're editing the correct php.ini file and checking `phpinfo()` from the correct SAPI. Remember that the PHP running from CLI and your Apache/web are two different binaries, that can load different configuration files. So you should have a look at `phpinfo()` from the correct one to find the "**Loaded configuration**" file to edit. You always need to restart PHP for these loaded configurations to take effect. Just keep in mind that `dl()` likely is removed from any current supported version of PHP.